# how to hide and display a menu using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

this is a menu item i need to display the menu only when browserName='mybrowser' otherwise i need to hide the menu. please help me how to hide and DISPLAY the menu? i m using a javascript code for checking the condition.

```
<div id="ddtopmenubar" class="mattblackmenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="web-hosting.php" rel="ddsubmenu1">HOSTING SERVICES</a> </li>
          <li><a href="price-match.php" rel="ddsubmenu2">PRICE MATCH</a> </li>
          <li><a href="ircd-accounts.php" rel="ddsubmenu3">IRC/UNIX</a> </li>
          <li><a href="https://clients.santrex.net/knowledgebase.php" rel="ddsubmenu4">SUPPORT</a></li>
          <li id="last"><a href="ourhistory.php" rel="ddsubmenu5">ABOUT SANTREX</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using CSS for this?

Answer (score 2):

Code to hide menu:

```
document.getElementById('ddtopmenubar').style.display = 'none';
```

Code to display menu:

```
document.getElementById('ddtopmenubar').style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 0):

Detecting browser:

```
var isOpera = !!(window.opera && window.opera.version);  // Opera 8.0+
var isFirefox = testCSS('MozBoxSizing');                 // FF 0.8+
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
    // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
var isChrome = !isSafari && testCSS('WebkitTransform');  // Chrome 1+
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || testCSS('msTransform');  // At least IE6
        if(isIE==true)//If IE, change it to any other as per need
        document.getElementById('ddtopmenubar').style.display = 'none';
```

Each test is fully independent of the other one, except for the Safari-Chrome test. To detect Chrome in a reliable way, you have to exclude Safari, since both share the webkit prefixes. But, if you only want to know whether the user is using Chrome 15+, the following can also be used:

```
 var isChrome = !!(window.chrome && chrome.webstore && chrome.webstore.install);
```

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/9zxvE/9/

or if you don't need browser detection

```
if( browserName='mybrowser' )
 document.getElementById('ddtopmenubar').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Question is about showing and hiding menu in javascript and not detecting browser.

Answer (score 0):

**See Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/cQPtk/2/

**Javascript:**

```
    var mybrowser = navigator.appName;

    if (mybrowser == 'Netscape') /* Change browser name accordingly */
        { document.getElementById('ddtopmenubar').style.display = 'block' }
    else
        { document.getElementById('ddtopmenubar').style.display = 'none' }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('ddtopmenubar').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('ddtopmenubar').style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery.

Here's one way to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/S8rtj/

Comment: `jQuery != JavaScript` OP said nothing about jQuery.

Comment: `jQuery !== Javascript`, otherwise, with type coercion, jQuery will probably equal javascript nowadays :D

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame Of course jQuery is JavaScript; what else would it be? C++? PHP? Plus, OP never said *not* to use jQuery either. By your logic we should never use any libraries or third-party code what so ever.